# Vertically aligning an img in a div in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, html, center, alignment

I am trying to vertically align images in a div in wordpress, the div is set as a kind of background border, which I've done, and I've got the images inside of the div center aligned horizontally but I cannot do it vertically, can anybody help?

Here are my classes at present, .image is the div and img is the images inside the post.

```
.entry img{max-width: 475px; max-height: 240px; padding: 50px;}
.entry .image{background-image:url(images/image-back.gif); width: 590; height:339px; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px;}
```

html code shows like this for each image in a post

```
<div class="image"><img src""></div>
```

any help is appreciated, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

The keystone of the solution in Internet Explorer: the internal object is absolutely positioned in half of the area height. Then is moved up by half of its height. The wrong interpretation of the height property in Internet Explorer is used (counted height is taken as a base of percentage height of nested tags). One extra nested tag  is needed for Explorer.

Solution for standard browsers like Mozilla, Opera, Safari etc. is completely different. Entire area (top ) is set to be displayed as a table (display: table; part of CSS2). The internal object is set as table-cell (display: table-cell). But -- there is the wit -- it is possible to use vertical-align property for such displayed element in standard browsers. (Internet Exlorer ignores those properties or doesn't know their values.)

Comment: There is only 1 div with an img tag inside, this code uses 3 divs? also not sure table cell works in ie?

Comment: Are you unable to add extra divs to make this work? Yeah the display:table does not work in IE, which is why it gives another solution for IE. Added above.

Comment: I am using wordpress so I'm not really able to add divs into the code, unless you have a solution for this?

Comment: You can edit anything you want in Wordpress if you know where to look :) Can you be more specific as to where this is occurring on your page? If you don't know about Firebug for Chrome or Developer tools for Chrome -- google them! They will help you find out.